# Vue - Data not computed in time before mount

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm learning Vue and I've run into a problem where my data returns undefined from a computed method. It seems that the data is not computed by the time the component is mounted, probably due to the get request - wrapping my `this.render()` in a `setTimeout` returns the data correctly. Setting a timeout is clearly not sensible so how should I be doing this for best practice?

Home.vue

```
export default {
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('retrievePost')
    },
    computed: {
        posts() {
            return this.$store.getters.getPosts
        }
    },
    methods: {
        render() {
            console.log(this.comments)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.render()
        }, 2000);
    },
}
```

store.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        posts: []
    },
    getters: {
        getPosts (state) {
            return state.posts
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        retrievePosts (state, comments) {
            state.posts = posts
        }
    },
    actions: {
        retrievePosts (context) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token

            axios.get('/posts')
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('retrievePosts', response.data)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: In render() functional you are trying to console this.comments? Where you defined it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because axios request is still processing when Vue invokes mounted hook(these actions are independent of each other), so `state.posts` are undefined as expected.

If you want to do something when posts loaded use `watch` or better `computed` if it's possible:

```
export default {
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('retrievePost')
    },
    computed: {
        posts() {
            return this.$store.getters.getPosts
        }
    },
    methods: {
        render() {
            console.log(this.comments)
        }
    },
    watch: {
       posts() { // or comments I dont see comments definition in vue object
           this.render();
       }
    }
}
```

P.S. And don't use `render` word as methods name or something because Vue instance has `render` function and it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply, this is what I was trying to do.